# lagrange multiplier---minimize

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

minimize $f(x,y,z)=x^2 + y^2+z^2 $
 constraint is $x^3+1 \leq 0 $

when I did this using slack variable I get $(x,y,z)=(-1,0,0) $
 but it is not working out using lagrange multiplier method.

Please help me out here.

thanks in advance

I understand I will need to use a slack variable to make an equality and will have
$x^3+1+S^2=0$

Comment: Please use MathJax when formatting your posts.

Comment: Hi you might want to take a look at this website: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions

Comment: Why not show your work using the Lagrange multiplier method?   It works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

With the Lagrange Multiplier, we check if the constraint is binding or non-binding. So we have:

$L(x, y, z, \lambda) = x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2} - \lambda(x^{3} + 1)$. We then check our first order conditions:

$2x - 3x^{2} \lambda = 0$ 
$2y = 0$ 
$2z = 0$

So if the constraint is binding, then $\lambda \neq 0$, and so $x = -1$. That gives us $\lambda = -\frac{2}{3}$. That gives us $f(-1, 0, 0) = 1$ as the minimum.

And if the constraint is non-binding, then $\lambda = 0$ and $x < -1$, which gives us $x^{2} > 1$.

Comment: omg, I was off only a little bit. If I had distributed the lagrange I would have gotten it. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Glad I could help!